# Error when using PyMedia to convert video to audio

Tags: python

I am getting a peculiar error while using PyMedia to convert video files (.avi) to audio files (.wav).

I get no error message - it just says python.exe has stopped working.

My code is [here](https://github.com/sohaibiftikhar/VideoToAudio/blob/ed3413fcef616ba30d0e61f6f37519eaf833aca3/extract.py). The two sample video clips are [here](https://github.com/sohaibiftikhar/VideoToAudio/blob/ed3413fcef616ba30d0e61f6f37519eaf833aca3/Samples/s30_di_4.avi) and [here](https://github.com/sohaibiftikhar/VideoToAudio/blob/ed3413fcef616ba30d0e61f6f37519eaf833aca3/Samples/s30_di_5.avi).

It works for the sample video [`s30_di_4.avi`](https://github.com/sohaibiftikhar/VideoToAudio/blob/ed3413fcef616ba30d0e61f6f37519eaf833aca3/Samples/s30_di_4.avi) but not for the sample video [`s30_di_5.avi`](https://github.com/sohaibiftikhar/VideoToAudio/blob/ed3413fcef616ba30d0e61f6f37519eaf833aca3/Samples/s30_di_5.avi) and fails with the above problem.

Can anyone please point out my mistake?

Comment: I've run into this problem with similar media modules. Normally, the problem for me was either in the filepaths (invalid filepaths like spaces in folders/cannot find path) or codecs. I'll look into this, but I need to get the modules first.

Comment: It looks like everything is working as it should be.. It might just be your video file(s30_di_5.avi). Have you tried other clips - do they all work?

Comment: Yeah most of them work. SOme of them show this peculiar behaviour though. But they play fine if I use a video player like vlc. So what could be the problem file ending?